# Model Look up table for a JPA Entity Field

Tags: jpa, associations, entity, lookup, relationships

I'm trying to find out the appropriate relationship to be used in order to model an JPA Entity Field which needs a Look-up table (Comboxbox equivalent on the UI) to select the value from. An example below:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private int employeeId;
    private String name;
    private Department department;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Department  {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

The instances of Department could be as follows:

```
Id    | Name
-----------------------
100   | Human Resources
101   | Sales
102   | Finances
```

For an employee, the department field should get a value from one of the above. What should be the JPA annotations for the corresponding fields in both the entities?

Thanks,

Sandeep Joseph

Comment: I'm sure if you actually read up on JPA, and did a search for OneToOne relation you may find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a unidirectional [ManyToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) relationship from `Employee` to `Department`, something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private int employeeId;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false)
    private Department department;
}
```

This means an employee must be associated to a single department and a department can be associated to many employees.

If you need to know the list of employees associated to a department then you can make the relationship bidirectional by adding this:

```
@Entity
public class Department  {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private Collection<Employee> employees; 
}
```

Comment: Thx dic19, I think this is the solution I wanted.